# react virtualized grid sort icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-virtualized

I've implemented on a grid from react-virtualized, the possibility for the user to sort values on click of an icon. I wish that the icon have the same behavior than the sort icon on [react-bootstrap table](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#sort).

Currently, my icon is working [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeCjP.gif). The column number doesn't come back to the circle icon, when I click on the column string.

Here's my sort component :

```
class SortColumn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      sortIcon: 'fa fa-circle',
      id: null,
    };
  }

  onClick() {
    const { columnId, sort } = this.props;
    const newSort = sort;
    newSort.id = columnId;

    if (sort.asc === true) {
      newSort.asc = false;
      this.setState({
        sortIcon: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        id: columnId,
      });
    } else if (sort.asc === false) {
      newSort.asc = true;
      this.setState({
        sortIcon: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        id: columnId,
      });
    }
    this.props.updateSort(newSort);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <i
        onClick={this.onClick}
        styleName="columnSettingsSort"
        className={this.state.sortIcon} aria-hidden="true"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the header icons to work similarly to how [react-virtualized `Table` headers work](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table).

The basic approach to this requires you to track both *sort-by* and *sort-direction* at the level of your `Grid`. You seem to be tracking it in component state at the level of a column which will run into the issue you've mentioned.

The easiest fix for this is just to move your component state for tracking the current sort criteria *from* your column component *into* your `updateSort` callback. Then pass the sort criteria to each column component as props. This way when a new sort direction is clicked, the old column will be informed (via new props) that it's no longer active.

Comment: I’m not sure I’ve understood everything. Here’s what I’ve did.

I have 3 components, GridView rendering ColumnHeader, rendering SortColumn. I’ve put in my GridView component the state of columnId and sort-direction. I’ve passed the sort-direction from GridView to SortColumn as props. In the render of SortColumn, I’m checking if the prop sort-direction is ascending or descending and display the corresponding icon.

Now, every time I’m clicking on SortColumn, it’s changing the icon of all the columns.

Did I miss or misunderstood something ?

Comment: Sounds like you're close! You also need to store the _sort by column_ itself. This way you know to only show the up/down arrow on the column that's currently being sorted by. The others should show whatever default UI they show when they're inactive. Make sense?